# Removal of an Attorney General

Tags: constitutional-law

The President nominates the Attorney General, and is responsible for seeing that the Attorney General faithfully upholds his duty to execute the laws of the land.  The Attorney General is subject to the policy direction of the President, and serves at the President's pleasure and discretion.

Why then, when the Attorney General is derelict in his duties, does it take the House to charge him and the Senate to try him, for him to be removed? Can't the President simply fire him?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the President can just fire them, or more commonly, request their resignation.

The provision for impeachment by Congress exists in case the President doesn’t do what the President should do.